# Print out Python console output to Qtextedit

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtextedit

I have the output like this, when I press the button:

> ['VERSION', 'ROMMON', 'HOSTNAME', 'UPTIME', 'RUNNING_IMAGE',
> 'HARDWARE', 'SERIAL', 'CONFIG_REGISTER']
>
> ['12.2(55)SE7', 'Bootstrap', 'Revo-Solusindo-01', '1 hour, 27
> minutes', 'c2960s-universalk9-mz.122-55.SE7.bin',
> ['WS-C2960S-24PD-L'], ['FOC1644Z129'], '0xF'] Write 1 records
>
> ['FAN', 'TEMPERATURE', 'TEMPERATURE_VALUE', 'TEMPERATURE_STATE',
> 'YELLOW_THRESHOLD', 'RED_THRESHOLD', 'POWER', 'RPS']
>
> ['OK', 'OK', '33', 'GREEN', '54', '64', '', ''] Write 1 records
>
> ['TOTAL', 'FFREE']
>
> ['57931776', '29178368']
>
> ['524288', '523212'] Write 2 records
>
> ['MEMTYPE', 'HEAD', 'TOTAL', 'USED', 'FREE', 'LOW', 'LARGE']
>
> ['Processor', '2BA9598', '73910760', '26908308', '47002452',
> '45367928', '30211716']
>
> ['      I/O', '6200000', '14680064', '12406764', '2273300', '2273300',
> '2273024']
>
> ['Driver te', '1A00000', '1048576', '44', '1048532', '1048532',
> '1048532'] Write 3 records
>
> ['CPU_5_SEC', 'CPU_1_MIN', 'CPU_5_MIN']
>
> ['10', '10', '9'] Write 1 records

How can I print the output of the background process to Qtextedit?

**My code:**

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import jtextfsm as textfsm

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQT tuts!")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('pythonlogo.png'))
        self.home()

    def home(self):
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Generate", self)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.TextFSM)
        btn.resize(100, 50)
        btn.move(50, 50)

        process  = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
        process.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.Start)
        process.ensureCursorVisible()
        process.setLineWrapColumnOrWidth(500)
        process.setLineWrapMode(QtGui.QTextEdit.FixedPixelWidth)
        process.setFixedWidth(400)
        process.setFixedHeight(150)
        process.move(50,100)

        self.show()

    def TextFSM(self):

        nameFile = 'Switch'

        try:
            input_file = open(nameFile + '.txt', encoding='utf-8')  # show version
            raw_text_data = input_file.read()
            input_file.close()

            input_file2 = open(nameFile + '.txt', encoding='utf-8')  # show env
            raw_text_data2 = input_file2.read()
            input_file2.close()

            input_file3 = open(nameFile + '.txt', encoding='utf-8')  # show flash
            raw_text_data3 = input_file3.read()
            input_file3.close()

            input_file4 = open(nameFile + '.txt', encoding='utf-8')  # show memory statistic
            raw_text_data4 = input_file4.read()
            input_file4.close()

            input_file5 = open(nameFile + '.txt', encoding='utf-8')  # show process cpu
            raw_text_data5 = input_file5.read()
            input_file5.close()

            template = open("show-version.textfsm")  # show version
            re_table = textfsm.TextFSM(template)
            fsm_results = re_table.ParseText(raw_text_data)

            template2 = open("show-env.textfsm")  # show env
            re_table2 = textfsm.TextFSM(template2)
            fsm_results2 = re_table2.ParseText(raw_text_data2)

            template3 = open("show-flash.textfsm")  # show flash
            re_table3 = textfsm.TextFSM(template3)
            fsm_results3 = re_table3.ParseText(raw_text_data3)

            template4 = open("show-memory-statistic.textfsm")  # show memory statistic
            re_table4 = textfsm.TextFSM(template4)
            fsm_results4 = re_table4.ParseText(raw_text_data4)

            template5 = open("show-process-cpu.textfsm")  # show process cpu
            re_table5 = textfsm.TextFSM(template5)
            fsm_results5 = re_table5.ParseText(raw_text_data5)

            outfile_name = open(nameFile + "-show-version.csv", "w+")  # show version
            outfile = outfile_name

            outfile_name2 = open(nameFile + "-show-env.csv", "w+")  # show env
            outfile2 = outfile_name2

            outfile_name3 = open(nameFile + "-show-flash.csv", "w+")  # show flash
            outfile3 = outfile_name3

            outfile_name4 = open(nameFile + "-show-memory-statistic.csv", "w+")  # show memory statistic
            outfile4 = outfile_name4

            outfile_name5 = open(nameFile + "-show-process-cpu.csv", "w+")  # show process cpu
            outfile5 = outfile_name5

            print(re_table.header)  # show version
            for s in re_table.header:
                outfile.write("%s;" % s)
            outfile.write("\n")

            counter = 0
            for row in fsm_results:  # show version
                print(row)
                for s in row:
                    outfile.write("%s;" % s)
                outfile.write("\n")
                counter += 1
            print("Write %d records" % counter)

            print(re_table2.header)  # show env
            for s in re_table2.header:
                outfile2.write("%s;" % s)
            outfile2.write("\n")

            counter = 0
            for row in fsm_results2:  # show env
                print(row)
                for s in row:
                    outfile2.write("%s;" % s)
                outfile2.write("\n")
                counter += 1
            print("Write %d records" % counter)

            print(re_table3.header)  # show flash
            for s in re_table3.header:
                outfile3.write("%s;" % s)
            outfile3.write("\n")

            counter = 0
            for row in fsm_results3:  # show flash
                print(row)
                for s in row:
                    outfile3.write("%s;" % s)
                outfile3.write("\n")
                counter += 1
            print("Write %d records" % counter)

            print(re_table4.header)  # show memory statistics
            for s in re_table4.header:
                outfile4.write("%s;" % s)
            outfile4.write("\n")

            counter = 0
            for row in fsm_results4:  # show memory statistics
                print(row)
                for s in row:
                    outfile4.write("%s;" % s)
                outfile4.write("\n")
                counter += 1
            print("Write %d records" % counter)

            print(re_table5.header)  # show process cpu
            for s in re_table5.header:
                outfile5.write("%s;" % s)
            outfile5.write("\n")

            counter = 0
            for row in fsm_results5:  # show process cpu
                print(row)
                for s in row:
                    outfile5.write("%s;" % s)
                outfile5.write("\n")
                counter += 1
            print("Write %d records" % counter)
        except IOError:
            print("Error: There Have File does not appear to exist.")
            QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Warning', "ERROR:Please check you're '.txt' file and TextFSM File.")


def run():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


run()
```

Comment: if someone have the example like my post, send to me.. thankss :)

Comment: You could share the files needed to run your code please.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B_jl0iXmYwS_SFdubDJwREJpOUU?usp=sharing... here's my files

Comment: try with my solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The output consoles produced by Python are written to the program output streams sys.stdout (normal output) and sys.stderr (error output, such as exception tracebacks). In this case we will use stdout

```
class Stream(QtCore.QObject):
    newText = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def write(self, text):
        self.newText.emit(str(text))

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQT tuts!")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('pythonlogo.png'))
        self.home()

        sys.stdout = Stream(newText=self.onUpdateText)

    def onUpdateText(self, text):
        cursor = self.process.textCursor()
        cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
        cursor.insertText(text)
        self.process.setTextCursor(cursor)
        self.process.ensureCursorVisible()

    def __del__(self):
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

Complete code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import jtextfsm as textfsm


class Stream(QtCore.QObject):
    newText = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def write(self, text):
        self.newText.emit(str(text))

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQT tuts!")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('pythonlogo.png'))
        self.home()

        sys.stdout = Stream(newText=self.onUpdateText)

    def onUpdateText(self, text):
        cursor = self.process.textCursor()
        cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
        cursor.insertText(text)
        self.process.setTextCursor(cursor)
        self.process.ensureCursorVisible()

    def __del__(self):
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__

    def home(self):

        w = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(w)
        lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(w)
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Generate")
        btn.clicked.connect(self.TextFSM)

        self.process  = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        self.process.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.Start)
        self.process.ensureCursorVisible()
        self.process.setLineWrapColumnOrWidth(500)
        self.process.setLineWrapMode(QtGui.QTextEdit.FixedPixelWidth)

        lay.addWidget(btn)
        lay.addWidget(self.process)

        self.show()

    def TextFSM(self):

        nameFile = 'Switch'

        try:
            input_file = open(nameFile + '.txt', encoding='utf-8')  # show version
            raw_text_data = input_file.read()
            input_file.close()

            input_file2 = open(nameFile + '.txt', encoding='utf-8')  # show env
            raw_text_data2 = input_file2.read()
            input_file2.close()

            input_file3 = open(nameFile + '.txt', encoding='utf-8')  # show flash
            raw_text_data3 = input_file3.read()
            input_file3.close()

            input_file4 = open(nameFile + '.txt', encoding='utf-8')  # show memory statistic
            raw_text_data4 = input_file4.read()
            input_file4.close()

            input_file5 = open(nameFile + '.txt', encoding='utf-8')  # show process cpu
            raw_text_data5 = input_file5.read()
            input_file5.close()

            template = open("show-version.textfsm")  # show version
            re_table = textfsm.TextFSM(template)
            fsm_results = re_table.ParseText(raw_text_data)

            template2 = open("show-env.textfsm")  # show env
            re_table2 = textfsm.TextFSM(template2)
            fsm_results2 = re_table2.ParseText(raw_text_data2)

            template3 = open("show-flash.textfsm")  # show flash
            re_table3 = textfsm.TextFSM(template3)
            fsm_results3 = re_table3.ParseText(raw_text_data3)

            template4 = open("show-memory-statistic.textfsm")  # show memory statistic
            re_table4 = textfsm.TextFSM(template4)
            fsm_results4 = re_table4.ParseText(raw_text_data4)

            template5 = open("show-process-cpu.textfsm")  # show process cpu
            re_table5 = textfsm.TextFSM(template5)
            fsm_results5 = re_table5.ParseText(raw_text_data5)

            outfile_name = open(nameFile + "-show-version.csv", "w+")  # show version
            outfile = outfile_name

            outfile_name2 = open(nameFile + "-show-env.csv", "w+")  # show env
            outfile2 = outfile_name2

            outfile_name3 = open(nameFile + "-show-flash.csv", "w+")  # show flash
            outfile3 = outfile_name3

            outfile_name4 = open(nameFile + "-show-memory-statistic.csv", "w+")  # show memory statistic
            outfile4 = outfile_name4

            outfile_name5 = open(nameFile + "-show-process-cpu.csv", "w+")  # show process cpu
            outfile5 = outfile_name5

            print(re_table.header)  # show version
            for s in re_table.header:
                outfile.write("%s;" % s)
            outfile.write("\n")

            counter = 0
            for row in fsm_results:  # show version
                print(row)
                for s in row:
                    outfile.write("%s;" % s)
                outfile.write("\n")
                counter += 1
            print("Write %d records" % counter)

            print(re_table2.header)  # show env
            for s in re_table2.header:
                outfile2.write("%s;" % s)
            outfile2.write("\n")

            counter = 0
            for row in fsm_results2:  # show env
                print(row)
                for s in row:
                    outfile2.write("%s;" % s)
                outfile2.write("\n")
                counter += 1
            print("Write %d records" % counter)

            print(re_table3.header)  # show flash
            for s in re_table3.header:
                outfile3.write("%s;" % s)
            outfile3.write("\n")

            counter = 0
            for row in fsm_results3:  # show flash
                print(row)
                for s in row:
                    outfile3.write("%s;" % s)
                outfile3.write("\n")
                counter += 1
            print("Write %d records" % counter)

            print(re_table4.header)  # show memory statistics
            for s in re_table4.header:
                outfile4.write("%s;" % s)
            outfile4.write("\n")

            counter = 0
            for row in fsm_results4:  # show memory statistics
                print(row)
                for s in row:
                    outfile4.write("%s;" % s)
                outfile4.write("\n")
                counter += 1
            print("Write %d records" % counter)

            print(re_table5.header)  # show process cpu
            for s in re_table5.header:
                outfile5.write("%s;" % s)
            outfile5.write("\n")

            counter = 0
            for row in fsm_results5:  # show process cpu
                print(row)
                for s in row:
                    outfile5.write("%s;" % s)
                outfile5.write("\n")
                counter += 1
            print("Write %d records" % counter)
        except IOError:
            print("Error: There Have File does not appear to exist.")
            QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Warning', "ERROR:Please check you're '.txt' file and TextFSM File.")


def run():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


run()
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: how if i have another function that run similar output like the example above it will automatically added to QLineText?

Comment: Exactly, all output you print will be sent to QTextEdit

Comment: Ok", its work well.. Thankss
btw, with my previously post i know how to calculate the time(each tasks) required.. i'm using time to get how long it's running.. it's right?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to add an additional function to [eyllanesc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44432276/print-out-python-console-output-to-qtextedit/44433766#44433766) to return standard output to defaults. Then there will not be any error pop up when closing the application.

```
def closeEvent(self, event):
    """Shuts down application on close."""
    # Return standard output to defaults.
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
    super().closeEvent(event)
```